# Facebook Comments, can't get moderator status

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I've got a facebook iframe page with the following (cut out irrelevant) code. I can't seem to become moderator of the comments. Any idea where i messed up?
(debugging link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=brandpreview.nl%2Ffbkerst%2Fwhitewishingboard.php)

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="737418775" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="240672092656980"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

            FB.init({
              appId      : '240672092656980', // App ID
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 2000 });

            // Additional initialization code here
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=240672092656980";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));       
    </script>       
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/brandrepublic.nl" data-num-posts="5" data-width="520"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't place your profile id inside those brackets. You should provide it without:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="737418775" />
```

Secondly, a requirement from Facebook has to be met; the facebook user who should get moderator priviliges needs to 'Like' your application.

Propably needless to say, but make sure you are logged in to Facebook when looking at your comment plugin.

Comment: Thanks, did fix the brackets and i do meet those other requirements. Still no luck.